# How do I rearrange bytes in a bytearray in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, arrays, swap, modbus

I am new to python and doing embedded-related work (most of my programming experience has been using C).

I am reading a four-byte float into a bytearray from a serial port but instead of the normal little-endian order DCBA, it is encoded as CDAB. Or it may be encoded as BADC. (where A is most significant byte and D is LSB). What is the correct way of swapping bytes around in a bytearray?

For example, I have

```
tmp=bytearray(pack("f",3.14))
```

I want to be able to arbitrarily arrange the bytes in tmp, and then unpack() it back into a float.

Things like this seem essential when doing anything related to embedded systems, but either I am googling it wrong or no clear answer is out there (yet!).

edit:
sure, I can do this:

```
from struct import *

def modswap(num):

    tmp=bytearray(pack("f",num))
    res=bytearray()
    res.append(tmp[2])
    res.append(tmp[3])
    res.append(tmp[0])
    res.append(tmp[1])
    return unpack('f',res)


def main():
    print(modswap(3.14))
```

but there has to be a better way...

Ideally, I would like to be able to slice and re-concatenate as I please, or even replace a slice at a time if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can swizzle in one step:

```
from struct import pack,unpack

def modswap(num):
    tmp=bytearray(pack("f",num))
    tmp[0],tmp[1],tmp[2],tmp[3] = tmp[2],tmp[3],tmp[0],tmp[1]
    return unpack('f',tmp)
```

You can modify a slice of a byte array:

```
>>> data = bytearray(b'0123456789')
>>> data[3:7] = data[5],data[6],data[3],data[4]
>>> data
bytearray(b'0125634789')
```

Comment: yes, but I want to to arbitrarily re-order the bytes. My question isn't about endianness. The specific application here is getting data from a Modbus device, which stores data only 2 bytes at a time, and the order of the 2-byte words in relation to the data being stored is unspecified and needs to be user-configurable. if big-endian is ABCD, and little endian is DCBA, I am asking about the proper way of handling cases like CDAB and BADC

Comment: Updated.  It would help to have a real, raw data example and what you want the result to be.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what to call it, swizzling seems like the perfect word xD

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and the closest answer is in this thread.

In Python3 the solution is:

```
b''.join((tmp[2:4],tmp[0:2]))
```